# dynamically generating plugin syntax

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, metabox, post-meta

I have downloaded an audio player plugin for WP. the syntax is very simple. You just add the line `[audio:my_file.mp3]` to your post editor/excerpt, and call it in the loop with `the_content()` or `the_excerpt()` respectively.

I would like to build a metabox in which the user would upload a file, and the plugin syntax would automatically be generated accordingly. I know how to insert the meta-data into the DB, but pulling it with `get_post_meta()` or `the_meta()` just gets the syntax as it is, without replacing it with the desired plugin content (i.e the audio player).

I thought about dynamically injecting the syntax to the editor/excerpt with the use of the filter `default_content` but this filter only applies to normal posts, whereas mine is a custom post type (audio). your ideas are most welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a custom TinyMCE button would be the ideal candidate for the job.

WordPress has [an excellent write-up in the codex on how to create one](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons); you'd essentially add a button to the TinyMCE toolbar with your own callback, which could trigger a modal pop-up to choose the audio file & insert the shortcode automatically.

Equally, you could hook into the output of media items once they've been uploaded, and display a link that would inject the shortcode for that item into the post (if uploaded within the Thickbox pop-up) - akin to how featured thumbnails work.

Check out `get_media_item()` and `get_attachment_fields_to_edit()` in `wp-admin/includes/media.php` for available hooks and filters.